# How to change body function means navigation without changing appbar and drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to change body function in flutter means navigation without changing appbar and drawer

Answer (score 0):

Place those `appbar` and `drawer` in the second screen too. Alternatively you can create a custom `scaffold` widget which can be reused in every screen. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'Tabs' approach.

1. Create a TabController
2. Create the tabs
3. Create content for each tab

#### References

- [Tabs well explained](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs)